# Goroutines are not iterating through a slice

Tags: go, concurrency

I have this code:

```
for _, v := range sams {
    sam := v
    pid := getPracticeIdBySam(db, sam)

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()

        for _, v := range pid {
            process(db, stmt, v, min_year, max_year, bar)
        }
    }()
}
```

It iterates through the first "pid", however it stops there. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: You would need to provide more context as there is not much we can tell from this snippet. For example, are you calling `wg.Add` at all? (for example `wg.Add(len(sams))` just before the loop)

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason. It is because I had `wg.Wait()` in `process` which in turn caused it to hang.